# Which is the right synthax for restoring on Windows from Bacula?

Tags: bacula

I have a full backup of a Windows 2008 R2-64bit. This server has two disks, C: and D:.
I'm too dumb to explain to Bacula (5.2.6) I want that what is labelled as "d:/" has to be restored to "D:\".
I have read the docs, googled a lot, experimented all the afternoon, but I'm still getting a "d" directory at the root of drive D:\, or a lot of error messages and no file restored.
Someone knows the logic behind the Bacula pathnames?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, difficult to find the write documentation for the restoring path, I also tried every things like dot (.), empty, but the correct answer is:
/
Bareos (or Bacula) will restore files in the original path.